# memcpy() - unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference

Tags: linked-list, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel module and I need to return to the user a lot of data.

I have a linked list with `log_list_head` as head (and it is empty) and the function `print_log()` that transfers the log_list data to a string and stores it in buffer.

```c
ssize_t my_read(struct file *filp, char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *offp)
{
    struct log_list *temp;
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char *)kmalloc(1024 * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
    temp = log_list_head->next;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        print_log(temp->data, buffer);
        copy_to_user(buff, buffer, strlen(buffer));  // This is not correct

        temp = temp->next;
    }
    copy_to_user(buff, message, strlen(buffer));
    kfree(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1. The user doesn't get anything, after running `print_log(buffer)`, it's empty
2. I know that `copy_to_user()` doesnt work to print multiple lines. Is there a way to return  string by string (I need to print it line by line) and I have been told that it can be very long?

I want to send the buffer to the user one at a time.

Comment: "But is there a way to return string by string" - You could use `seq_file` functionality for write a data to the user in a chunks. See e.g. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/filesystems/seq_file.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are overwriting the user buff every time.

If you make `buffer` large enough to hold the maximum size of data + message, you can do it in one shot:

```
int i=0;
while (temp != NULL){
    print_log(temp->data, buffer+i);  //offset by amount already done
    i = strlen(buffer);
    temp=temp->next;
}
strcat(buffer, message);
copy_to_user(buff, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);  // include terminator
```

It could be made more efficient if print_log kept track of the end of the buffer, but that's likely premature optimization.

Comment: With such a rating you should know how to enable syntax highlitng (besides other small formatting issues that makes readability better).

Comment: Besides above, your code fixes are not good enough as they have security and performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

For future people who come here.
The reason it didn't work is because i returned 0 and not buf length